# bx slider loads broken the snaps into place

Tags: jquery, bxslider

in all browsers my bxSlider loads without styling and shows all the levels, and shifted to the left until the script kicks in and it snaps into place.

I tried setting the div it is in with style="display:none" and then lower on the page place this
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div-id').css({'display': 'block'}).animate();
               });
I have tried several different syntax but for the life of me I can't get it to work.
anybody see something obvious or have an idea

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
$('#div-id').css('display','block');
```

rather than

```
$('#div-id').css({'display': 'block'}).animate();
```

html:

```
<div id="div-id"><ul class="slider"><li><a rel="gallery" href="img/carousel/1.jpg"><img src="img/carousel/1.jpg" width="170" height="150" /></a></li></ul></div>
```

css:

```
#div-id {display: none}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('#div-id').css('display','block'); });
```

Alternatively, as in my example I was using a ul tag, the following works equally as well:
html (no need for div):

```
<ul class="slider"><li><a rel="gallery" href="img/carousel/1.jpg"><img src="img/carousel/1.jpg" width="170" height="150" /></a></li></ul>
```

css:

```
.slider ul {    display:none;   }
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      $('.slider ul').css('display','block');  });
```